# Overwriting Existing Reports with SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SQL Server Report instance that is acting strange.  I can do everything but overwrite an existing report.  I can open a current report, run it, and save it as a different report no problem, but any attempt to save an existing one times out after 2 minutes.  Looking at the Report Server logs I can confirm it is a timeout that it is returning.

Has anyone experienced this before, and more importantly, figured out how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going through a direct connection rather than the shared connection.  There was a contention with one of the meta tables being locked, and this proved to be not a solution, but at least a work-around.